# Execute SSIS task regardless of preceding step without concurrency

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package that looks like this:

[image: This is my flow]

---

**What I need**

1. The tasks should execute in sequence, so the precedence constrains should be maintained.
2. Execution of each task is not dependant on the previous task, even if the previous task didn't execute at all.
3. Execution of each task is dependant on a boolean variable.

So in the example above the following ***should*** happen:

1. `IP` will execute
2. `ST1` will execute because:

   1. `IP` is complete; and
   2. `@[User::doOne] = True`
3. `ST2` will execute because:

   1. `ST1` is complete; and
   2. `@[User::doTwo] = True`
4. `ST3` will execute because:

   1. `ST2` is complete; and
   2. `@[User::doThree] = True`
5. `ST4` will ***not*** execute because:

   1. `ST3` is complete; and
   2. `@[User::doFour] = False`
6. `ST5` ***will*** execute because:

   1. `ST4` is "complete" (skipped); and
   2. `@[User::doFive] = True`
7. `OP` will execute

---

**What I tried**

I thought I could set all the precedence constraints to `Complete` but then the execution of `ST5` is still dependant on `ST4` executing which it won't since `@[User::doFour] = False` and the precedence constraint from `ST3` to `ST4` will hence prevent `ST4` from executing.

I thought that if I connected each task to each task after it in the intended flow it would work, but then I'll have concurrency, which I can't have here, or the same issue as noted above.

I tried looking for a different task in the toolbox but couldn't find anything that might make this work.

I also thought that maybe I could create a loop (below).

[image: This is the loop flow I attempted]

Each task would return to a previous task, in this case `ST1` through `ST5` would point back to `PI` and from there to `DTSBTR`, which would use some logic to direct the process flow, but BIDS detects the potential infinite loop and prevents it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish with the use of sequence containers.

1. Put a sequence container around st1
2. Connect IP to the Sequence container and change the constraint to "Completion," so that the ST1 container will always execute
3. Add a script task to the container before ST1, but do not configure it to do anything
4. Add a constraint between the task that does nothing and ST1 and change the constraint to run based on the expression, referencing the appropriate variable
5. Do the same container pattern with the rest of the tasks.

Please see the attached example:

[image: SSIS Sequence Container Pattern]

Comment: That makes sense! I'm going to try it now and will respond shortly. By the way, why does your tasks look so pretty? Is it 2012 or something?

Comment: It's 2012, they cleaned up the UI for accessibility purposes.  Logic will be the same though.